# How to override camera controls in OpenTok React-Native

Tags: react-native, expo, opentok

I'm using [OpenTok React-Native](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native) in my Expo React-Native app. I want to be able to control the publisher video, including zoom, white balance and focus. The video will be both streamed live and available as a recording using the Tokbox archiving feature, so the controls need to affect both the live and the recorded video.

How can I control these settings whilst using OpenTok React Native? I see Expo has a [camera module](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v43.0.0/sdk/camera/) which has these features. Is there any way to utilize that module with OTRN?

Here is how I'm using the library

```
<OTSession
  apiKey={apiKey}
  sessionId={sessionId}
  token={token}
>
  <OTPublisher
    eventHandlers={{
      audioLevel: handleSetRawAudioLevel,
      error: (error) =>
        log.error('Publisher error', { error: error.message }),
      otrnError: (error) =>
        log.error('Publisher OTRN error', { error: error.message }),
      streamCreated: handleTeacherStreamCreated,
      streamDestroyed: handleTeacherStreamDestroyed,
    }}
    properties={{
      publishAudio: !isLoadingClassData,
      publishVideo: !isLoadingClassData,
    }}
    style={styles.teacherFeed}
  />
</OTSession>
```

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to utilize that library directly. A way around would be using the screen share functionality of OpenTok to share the output of the Expo camera module, but I am not sure if the quality will hold. 

You would need to implement a custom video driver natively for iOS and android to achieve those sorts of things. Which will then need to be patched into OpenTok React-Native.

I would recommend trying the scene sharing workaround and I can speak to the engineering team to see if there are any other alternatives

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, screen sharing would not work for my case, since the screen shows multiple subscriber videos that cannot be in the recorded archive.